# How can I work in nested monads cleanly?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm writing an interpreter for a small language.
This language supports mutation, so its evaluator keeps track of a `Store` for all the variables (where `type Store = Map.Map Address Value`, `type Address = Int`, and `data Value` is a language-specific ADT).

It's also possible for computations to fail (e.g., dividing by zero), so the result has to be an `Either String Value`.

The type of my interpreter, then, is

```
eval :: Environment -> Expression -> State Store (Either String Value)
```

where `type Environment = Map.Map Identifier Address` keeps track of local bindings.

For example, interpreting a constant literal doesn't need to touch the store, and the result always succeeds, so

```
eval _ (LiteralExpression v) = return $ Right v
```

But when we apply a binary operator, we do need to consider the store.
For example, if the user evaluates `(+ (x <- (+ x 1)) (x <- (+ x 1)))` and `x` is initially `0`, then the final result should be `3`, and `x` should be `2` in the resulting store.
This leads to the case

```
eval env (BinaryOperator op l r) = do
    lval <- eval env l
    rval <- eval env r
    return $ join $ liftM2 (applyBinop op) lval rval
```

Note that the `do`-notation is working within the `State Store` monad.
Furthermore, the use of `return` is monomorphic in `State Store`, while the uses of `join` and `liftM2` are monomorphic in the `Either String` monad.
That is, here we use

```
(return . join) :: Either String (Either String Value) -> State Store (Either String Value)
```

and `return . join` is not a no-op.

(As is evident, `applyBinop :: Identifier -> Value -> Value -> Either String Value`.)

This seems confusing at best, and this is a relatively simple case.
The case of function application, for example, is considerably more complicated.

What useful best practices should I know about to keep my code readable—and writable?

**EDIT:** Here's a more typical example, which better showcases the ugliness.
The `NewArrayC` variant has parameters `length :: Expression` and `element :: Expression` (it creates an array of a given length with all elements initialized to a constant).
A simple example is `(newArray 3 "foo")`, which yields `["foo", "foo", "foo"]`, but we could also write `(newArray (+ 1 2) (concat "fo" "oo"))`, because we can have arbitrary expressions in a `NewArrayC`.
But when we actually call

```
allocateMany :: Int -> Value -> State Store Address,
```

which takes the number of elements to allocate and the value for each slot, and returns the starting address, we need to unpack those values.
In the logic below, you can see that I'm duplicating a bunch of logic that should be built-in to the `Either` monad.
All the `case`s should just be binds.

```
eval env (NewArrayC len el) = do
    lenVal <- eval env len
    elVal <- eval env el
    case lenVal of
        Right (NumV lenNum) -> case elVal of
            Right val   -> do
                addr <- allocateMany lenNum val
                return $ Right $ ArrayV addr lenNum  -- result data type
            left        -> return left
        Right _             -> return $ Left "expected number in new-array length"
        left                -> return left
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what monad transformers are for. There is a `StateT` transformer to add state to a stack, and an `EitherT` transformer to add `Either`-like failure to a stack; however, I prefer `ExceptT` (which adds `Except`-like failure), so I will give my discussion in terms of that. Since you want the stateful bit outermost, you should use `ExceptT e (State s)` as your monad.

```
type DSL = ExceptT String (State Store)
```

Note that the stateful operations can be spelled `get` and `put`, and these are polymorphic over all instances of `MonadState`; so that in particular they will work okay in our `DSL` monad. Similarly, the canonical way to raise an error is `throwError`, which is polymorphic over all instances of `MonadError String`; and in particular will work okay in our `DSL` monad.

So now we would write

```
eval :: Environment -> Expression -> DSL Value
eval _ (Literal v) = return v
eval e (Binary op l r) = liftM2 (applyBinop op) (eval e l) (eval e r)
```

You might also consider giving `eval` a more polymorphic type; it could return an `(MonadError String m, MonadState Store m) => m Value` instead of a `DSL Value`. In fact, for `allocateMany`, it's important that you give it a polymorphic type:

```
allocateMany :: MonadState Store m => Int -> Value -> m Address
```

There's two pieces of interest about this type: first, because it is polymorphic over all `MonadState Store m` instances, you can be just as sure that it only has stateful side effects as if it had the type `Int -> Value -> State Store Address` that you suggested. However, also because it is polymorphic, it can be specialized to return a `DSL Address`, so it can be used in (for example) `eval`. Your example `eval` code becomes this:

```
eval env (NewArrayC len el) = do
    lenVal <- eval env len
    elVal  <- eval env el
    case lenVal of
        NumV lenNum -> allocateMany lenNum elVal
        _           -> throwError "expected number in new-array length"
```

I think that's quite readable, really; nothing too extraneous there.

Comment: You're right that I "want the stateful bit outermost" (in particular, this is because identifier lookup can fail depending on the state), but I don't understand how using `ExceptT String (State Store)` instead of `StateT Store (Either String)` accomplishes this. In fact, [this post seems to suggest otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5076096/732016) as well. Could you please explain?

Comment: Just keep expanding newtypes until you get something at the base. You'll see the difference pretty quick: `ExceptT String (State Store) a` expands to `Store -> (Store, Either String a)` while `StateT Store (Except String) a` expands to `Store -> Either String (Store, a)`. Which you want is up to you, of course.

Comment: One last question—it seems that `Control.Monad.Error` is deprecated, but `Control.Monad.Error.Class` is not; is that correct? (I'm not able to find any `Control.Monad.Except.Class`.)

Comment: @WChargin Yep, `C.M.E.Class` is fine.